# Is possible mail validation in html5 without require?

Tags: html, forms, validation

For example is that form:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="name" required /> <br />
<input type="email" name="email" /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Now!">
```

It is possible to valid correct email format using html5, but this input is not required?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the "formnovalidate" attribute.

an example is shown [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp)